# CSV files are opening as a page

Tags: php, html, csv, download

I am new to web development and I am facing an abnormal issue with the CSV files.

I have a link to download a CSV file:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/public/sample.csv">Sample CSV file</a>
```

On my local machine it gives a dialog box for the download - *that is correct and that is what I want*.

When I upload the same code to my web server, it opens the csv file as a web page in the same browser tab. That I don't want, **I want a dialog box for the download option**!

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or What I need to do?

Comment: Check the `Content-type` returned by your local machine and by your web server. Also, use less punctuation in your questions. `!!!!!` doesn't really add any value.

Comment: @Wesley : Yes I am using Apache Server

Comment: @Noufal : Thanks for the advise, will keep in mind next time :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following line to your .htaccess. All the CSV files will be forced to download if opened.
`AddType application/octet-stream csv`
It will add the MIME header to all csv files, so browser will understand that it needs to download the file, not show it.

Comment: Please. It's `text/csv` and not `application/octet-stream`. The option to download is something you should leave to the client. The server should report the correct mime type and then use `Content-disposition` to tell the client to open a download box.

Comment: Noufal, what if he has link "download CSV"?

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: I think you're correct about the mime type, but I assume it's the same client in both cases, the OP's browser. I don't know why someone would want CSV to open in a browser tab, but the answer here is just trying to make sure the right header is sent. I think there are several possible mimes that could work. I'd guess most folks will get a download dialog without the need to use content-disposition.

Comment: Make sure you have that line in `.htaccess` file inside the directory (or any of parent directories) that has your CSV files.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: If he sets it to `application/octet-stream`, a client that wants to associate a certain program to open `csv` files is at a loss. Servers should return correct headers. Abusing them to create a download dialog is a last resort and best avoided if possible.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: Great point, the user may have Excel set as the default program for CSV so it opens right away from the browser, and this would depend on the correct CSV header. Am I correct in thinking that `application/octet-stream` is sort of a "generic", last-resort mime type?

Comment: Generally speaking, unknown binary data. It's often used as a "default".